# Como fazer um script autônomo usando o Global.asa

Tags: vba, automatização, asp

Estou querendo executar um script que grave informações no banco de dados a cada 24 horas. Não sou o administrador do server, então não tenho acesso a `Scheduled Tasks`, li em alguns artigos que posso utilizar o `Global.asa` para toda vez que o site for visitado (usando o Session_OnStart), contar 24 horas e rodar o script.

Tentei aplicar essa forma mas não funcionou; 
Segue o código em asp clássico:

```
<!-- #include file="etc/conexao.asp" -->

<script language="vbscript" runat="server">

Sub Session_OnStart
   'Runs on application start or after 15 minutes
   If Application("LastRun") = "" Or DateDiff(n, Application("LastRun"), Now()) > 15 Then

    set RS = server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Recordset")
    set RS2 = server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Recordset")

'exemplo de query que irá roda:
    RS2.Open "SELECT numero from PI_TESTES WHERE ID = 5",conn,1
    numero = RS2("numero")

    numero = numero + 2

    RS.Open "UPDATE PI_TESTES SET numero = '"&numero&"' "+_ 
    "WHERE ID = '5' ",conn,1

       Application("LastRun") = Now()
   End If
End Sub


</SCRIPT>
```

Se alguém tiver alguma outra solução, também estou disposto a adotar.

Comment: Envolve algum sistema web? Posso propor uma solução que utiliza seu site hospedado.

Comment: É intranet, não posso utilizar "soluções/serviços externas" @MaiconCarraro :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema de utilizar o `Global.asa` é que não garante que seu script vai ser executado toda vez, se ele não estiver constantemente em uso o IIS pode parar o processo depois de um tempo então não é garantido que você vai rodar o script.

Se estiver utilizando `Windows`, você pode utilizar o agendador da tarefas ou pelo `cmd` o comando `schtasks`.

Exemplo:

```
schtasks /Create /SC DAILY /ST 10:00:00 /ET 10:10 /K /TN rotina /TR "'C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe' \"http://ip_intranet/aplicacao/rotina.asp""
```

- `/Create` - Criar a tarefa.
- `/SC` - Frequência que vai executar a tarefa, no caso DAILY = Diariamente
- `/ST` - Hora de executar a tarefa, no caso 10h.
- `/ET` - Hora para finalizar a tarefa, no caso 10h10.
- `/K` - Finaliza a tarefa de acordo com o `ET`.
- `/TN` - Nome da tarefa, no caso 'rotina'.
- `/TR` - Comando a ser executado, no caso ele abre o navegador do `IExplorer` e abre a url `"http://ip_intranet/aplicacao/rotina.asp"`

Qual o truque aqui?

Você cria essa página `rotina.asp` fazendo todo o `SELECT/UPDATE` que precisa. Então toda vez que ele executar a tarefa vai abrir a página, fazendo uma requisição desde que esteja na mesma rede `intranet` e abrir a `rotina.asp`.

Comment: Obrigado. Contactei o administrador do servidor e ele rodou a rotina. Realmente o global.asa é muito bugado - Todos os experimentos que testei nele não funcionaram.

Answer (score 3):

Se fosse ASP.Net seria mais fácil por conseguir usar quartz.net mas no asp clássico é mais complicado. Eu sugiro a você três"gambiarras" que você poderá analisar e escolher a que melhor te atende.

Primeira:

1. Agende a sua máquina pessoal para rodar a página asp ou vbs que faz o serviço diariamente.

O problema aqui é que você tem que ter permissão para agendar a tarefa e caso sua máquina seja desligada por algum motivo ou ficar fora da rede não irá rodar.

Segunda:

1. Crie uma conta grátis no [newrelic](https://www.newrelic.com)
2. Adicione um monitor no synthetics ([synthetics.newrelic.com](https://synthetics.newrelic.com)) que roda a cada 24 horas chamando sua página rotina.asp

Essa solução só funciona em sites que são públicos. Ou seja, podem ser acessados pela internet, não funcionando em intranets, e caso o seu servidor esteja fora na hora programada poderá ficar sem rodar.

Terceira:

1. Peça a equipe de suporte para programar o recycle do servidor para ser feito todo dia em determinado horário
2. Coloque o seu código no application_start do global.asa

Essa solução irá rodar sempre no primeiro acesso após o recycle, então a hora poderá variar. Outro problema é que pode rodar mais de uma vez por dia e você terá que controlar isso via código. Mas apesar de variar o horário e poder rodar mais de uma vez por dia, essa solução é a que mais garante que seu código rodará todo dia.
Se for um site público você poderá criar um monitor no newrelic, rodando de 1 em 1 minuto acessando qualquer página do site, garantindo que assim que for feito o recycle seu código rodará. E de quebra, terá um relatório de uptime/downtime e performance do seu sistema.

Desculpe dar soluções estranhas mas asp clássico é complicado. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta e dedicação, infelizmente não posso usar um serviço externo pois o site é na intranet. Mas irei guardar a sua resposta para uso futuro!

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que uma solução melhor seria utilizar um scheduler no evento `Application_Start` da sua aplicação. Esse scheduler sería disparado apenas uma vez e executado de 24 em 24 horas.

O [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) é um bom exemplo de uma boa ferramenta para isso.

Você pode também implementar um schedulador, mas seria "reinventar a roda",  contudo um exercício bem interessante.

Comment: Obrigado pela indicação do serviço!